# How do i remove multiple numbers based on a search of multiple node values?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am fairly new to XSLT and have scanned through several posts on the topic but cant seem to get the final peice i need to make this work.  I am attempting to remove entries from a known string of data that appear in the node data that i have.  I have peiced together a solution that works for single node values but not multiple values.

here is my xml

```
<root>
<item>2</item>
<item>9</item>
<item>5</item>
</root>
```

here is my code that works for one node value:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:call-template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:with-param name="original" select="string('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10')"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:param name="original"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($original, current())">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($original, current())"/>
<xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($original, current())"/>
<xsl:variable name="char" select="substring-before($after, current())"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($char, $after)"/>
<xsl:call-template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:with-param name="original" select="substring-after($after, current())"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="$original"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

my latest of testing i am attempting to use this:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:call-template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:with-param name="original" select="string('1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10')"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:param name="original"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains($original, current())">
<xsl:variable name="before" select="substring-before($original, current())"/>
<xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($original, current())"/>
<xsl:variable name="char" select="substring-before($after, current())"/>
<xsl:variable name="new" select="concat($before, $after)"/>
<xsl:call-template name="replaceChars">
<xsl:with-param name="original" select="$new"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="$original"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

i contiune to get the value iterated several times in the response.  i would like my output to be the following:

1 3 4 6 7 8 10

I have searched on this extensively as you can see my example is based on an altered searched scenario.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

If you want to produce the string "1 3 4 6 7 8 10" once, then you probably don't want the code you show to be evaluated once for each `item` element, but once for each `root` element.

If you want the recursive template `replaceChars` to knock out the value of each `item` in the set of sibling `item` elements, then the current structure won't do it.  Why?  Because it knocks out the value of `current()` and then calls itself recursively *without doing anything to change the value of `current()`*.

One alternative approach would be to say "I want to build a string consisting of the number 1 (unless it appears in the input), followed by the number 2 (unless it appears in the input), followed by ..." and write (n.b. not tested):

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <survivors>
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '1')">1 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '2')">2 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '3')">3 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '4')">4 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '5')">5 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '6')">6 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '7')">7 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '8')">8 </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:if test="not(./item = '9')">9 </xsl:if> 
  </survivors>
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you really want to do the substring-match thing, you need to ensure that your recursion in `replaceChars` actually iterates over the `item` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <survivors>
    <xsl:call-template name="replaceChars2">
      <xsl:with-param name="s" select="'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="item" select="./item[1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </survivors>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replaceChars2">
  <xsl:param name="s"/>
  <xsl:param name="item"/>
  <xsl:variable name="s2" select="string($item)"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$item">
      <xsl:call-template name="replaceChars2">
        <xsl:with-param name="s" 
          select="concat(
            substring-before($s,$s2,
            ' ',
            substring-after($s,$s2,
            )"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="item" 
          select="./following-sibling::item[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Like the code shown by the OP, this assumes no `item` element will accidentally match any part of the string that should not be deleted (e.g. the original string will never have a value like '11' if any item will ever have the value '1').

The pattern of iterating over siblings and passing parameters to keep track of what happened with the earlier siblings is an important idiom to learn, for transforms like this one.

Comment: thank you for the detailed information and teaching i will review this

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:sent/>
 <xsl:variable name="vSent" select="document('')/*/my:sent"/>

 <xsl:param name="pGiven" select="'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="item[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="$pGiven"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "following-sibling::item[1]|$vSent[not(current()/following-sibling::item)]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
    "concat(substring-before(concat($pText, .), .),
            substring-after($pText,.)
            )
    "/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="my:sent">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>5</item>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
1  3 4  6 7 8  10
```

**Do note**:

1. **There is no XSLT conditional instruction** in the whole transformation -- no `xsl:choose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwise` no `xsl:if` .
2. **There is no named template and no explicit recursion** (although `xsl:apply-templates` recurses implicitly).
3. **[Sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) programming is used** in two different ways to significantly simplify the code and make it more efficient.

Comment: @user1672039, Please, do let me know if you have any questions, or when you have successfully used this solution.